# load different files from a container in azure blob storage to different tables using azure data factory copy activity

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-blob-storage

We have a requirement to copy multiple files from a blob container to azure db and on successful completion archive them into another container and delete the files in source container.I used two copy activities and one delete activity(with recursive option) for this and was able to load files with same structure to azure data base and then archive them into another container in blob.

But now,we have requirement to load multiple files of different structure in a container to azure database tables based on file name,can you please help in loading multiples files to azure db dynamically using azure data factory.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will have to parameterized both the source and sink linked service . This may help you .
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/53367.azure-data-factory-v2-copy-content-of-multiple-blob-to-different-sql-tables.aspx

Comment: Hi Himanshu,thanks for sharing the link.It was very helpful.I tried to follow as specified in the link,but in my case both the files data was loading into a single table.I checked in the set variable activity output of getfilename,tablename both files are showing but in copy activity both the files data is loading into a single table.Can you please let me know if i am missing anything.Please find the link below for the steps that i followed.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/uuhrscowwiyijzb/load%20multiple%20files.rtf?dl=0

Comment: Please remove the parameter from DelimitedText DS_test dataset ( named Filename)


In the Copy activity -> Sink -> DS_test_azureDB _ Please add the 
Table as "dbo" without quotes and @dataset().tablename
It will look like dbo.@dataset().tablename , 

My apologizes,I had forget to put that in the initial doc , i just updated that now as step 6.1

HTH

Comment: Hi Himanshu,removed the filename parameter from DelimitedText DS_test dataset and added @dataset().table in sink dataset.This time two tables are created but the schema of both tables is same as first file and copy activity of the pipeline failed as the schema of table2 didn't match with second file metadata.I think there is still something is missing because both the tables are created with same schema.Can you please recreate the scenario as we are missing something in between.Please find the below link that i followed this time.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/84ky7q974tr9bwa/load%20multiple%20files-1.docx?dl=0

Comment: I am so sorry that its still not work for you . I think the you have set the Recursively option . Can you please go to the Copy activity -> Source -> Uncheck Recursively 
also I think you have set the Wildcard folder , please set that as blank and try again .

Comment: Hi Himanshu,tried that as well.Removed the recursive option in copy activity source and debugged but pipeline validation failed  with message as 'Dataset DS_test location is a folder, the wildcard file name is required for Copy data1'.So used * for Wildcard file name and this time pipeline started.But at the end same result two tables created with same structure of first file and copy activity for second file failed as the schema of second table didn't match with second file.

Comment: I need to trouble shoot this further , please do drop an email to AzCommunity@microsoft.com and we can work on this further .

Comment: Hi Himanshu,I tried using @{variables('FileName')} for Wildcard file name in source copy activity and it worked.This time two tables created with the structure of their respective source files and data also loaded into these tables as per the files.

Comment: Great news, if you think that the blog helped , please up vote this answer so that others can benefit from it .